# Show audio in the notification bar

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently programming an audio player and I don't know how to get the current song into the notification bar on my mobile phone. That I have a mini audio player there.
Do I need certain dependencies and if so, which ones?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at https://github.com/tanguyantoine/react-native-music-control

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.